# Power Bi Gateway - server migration

Tags: powerbi, gateway, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-desktop

I have a BI enterprise gateway setup, I also have many datasets and reports.

Recently I have moved to a new server. I have successfully installed the gateway on the new server using the recovery method.

So now I have moved to the new server the server name and credentials have changed. Whilst I have added the new database to the gateway the other one is still left in there.

So my question is...

Will I need to go through every report / dataset and change the connection, what is the safest way to do this?

Once I've done that can I just remove the old connection from the gateway leaving the new one in?

Thanks in advance